# Remove a grouping var in custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function that adjusts the grouping vars to exclude a single grouping var.  The function is always passed a grouped tibble.  The first part of the function does some calculations at the grouping level it's supplied.  The second part does additional calculations, but needs to exclude a single grouping var that's dynamic in my data. Using the mtcars as a sample dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

# x is a grouped tibble, my_col is the column to peel
my_function <- function(x, my_col){

    my_col_enc <- enquo(my_col)

    # Trying to grab the groups and then peel off the column
    x_grp <- x %>% group_vars()
    excluded <- x_grp[!is.element(x_grp, as.character(my_col_enc))]

    # My calculations are two-tiered as described in the original description
    # simplifying for example
    x %>% group_by(excluded) %>% tally()

}

# This should be equivalent to mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% tally()
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% my_function(cyl)
```

When I run this, I get an Error: Column 'excluded' is unknown.

Edit:
For any future searchers with this issue, if you have a character vector (i.e. multiple grouping vars), you may need to use syms with !!! to achieve what my original question was asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
  library(tidyverse)

  my_function <- function(x, my_col){

    my_col_enc <- enquo(my_col)

    # Trying to grab the groups and then peel off the column
    x_grp <- x %>% group_vars()

    # here, make sure this is a symbol, else it'll group as character later (e.g. 'gear')
    excluded <- rlang::sym(x_grp[!is.element(x_grp, as.character(my_col_enc))])

    # need to use !'s to deal with the symbol
    x %>% group_by(!!excluded) %>% tally()
  }
```

I commented the code, but you're first problem was that your `excluded` variable wasn't recognized: to make indirect references to columns, it is necessary to modify the quoted code before it gets evaluated. Do this with the `!!` (pronounced 'bang bang') operator.

Adding just that to your code won't completely solve it, because `excluded` is a character. It needs to be treated as a symbol, hence the `rlang::sym()` function wrapping its declaration.

Comment: I tried it with !! at first, but was missing the symbol treatment.  Thanks for the great explanation of the issue.